# How to keep area of canvas centered in a ScrollViewer when Zoomed in or out, and not everything can be displayed in the viewing window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, zooming

Everyone,

I have a WPF app that has a canvas that I have wrapped in a scroll Viewer.  I have a slider in the status bar that allows the user to zoom in and out (just like Win 7's mspaint).

Here is some of the XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="Map"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Canvas x:Name="WallsCanvas" Height="800" Width="1000" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="WallsCanvasScale"
                            ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
        </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

When I zoom in, and the scrollbars are visible, the scrollbars, no matter where they are set, jump to the middle.

It is exactly as if the value of the scrollbars stay the same but the max value increases.

What can I do to get them to ... say, if they were in the lower right corner, to stay in the lower right corner after a zoom in or out?

BTW, here is my Zoom in and out code:

```
private void SliderValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    var scales = new []{.125, .25, .5, 1, 2, 4, 8};
    var scale = scales[(int)((Slider) sender).Value];

    ScaleChanged(scale, WallsCanvasScale);
}

private static void ScaleChanged(double scale, ScaleTransform st)
{
    st.ScaleX = scale;
    st.ScaleY = scale;
}
```

So, no rocket science in my code but ...

Update idea: If I had access to the value and the max value of the scrollbars, could I get the percentage between the two and then after the zooming (scaling) I could re-apply the value of the scrollbar as a percentage of the max value?????  But where is the value and the max value available?

Any help would be appreciated.  I cannot think that I am the only one that has this problem since MSPaint (the Windows 7 version) works correctly and I assume it is a XAML app.

Here is a [link](http://www.leesaunders.net/examples/zoomexample/zoomexample.zip) (http://www.leesaunders.net/examples/zoomexample/zoomexample.zip) to a minimum working example project (VS 2010).  When you run it, just move the scroll bars then zoom in a level, you will see the issue right away.

Comment: The center properties do not set a relative percentage value, currently your center is half a pixel to the right and half a pixel down from the upper left corner.

Comment: OK, so technically I do not even need to define CenterX and CenterY.  Thanks for that little oops.  If only the original question was that easy to fix. :-)

Comment: (H.B.) I removed the Center properties from both the example and my source code.  Thanks again.

Comment: Could you possibly show the complete code/upload some project which reliably demonstrates this bahavior? The scrollbars should not jump normally.

Comment: (H.B.) I've added a link at the end of my question with a minimum working example project (VS 2010)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to offset the shift which results from the scale because it scales from (0,0). It's a bit complicated but here's a sketch of what the method in your sample could look like:

```
private void SliderValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    var slider = (Slider)sender;
    if (!slider.IsLoaded)
    {
        slider.Loaded += (s, le) => SliderValueChanged(sender, e);
        return;
    }

    var scales = new[] { .125, .25, .5, 1, 2, 4, 8 };
    var scale = scales[(int)((Slider)sender).Value];

    // The "+20" are there to account for the scrollbars... i think. Not perfectly accurate.
    var relativeMiddle = new Point((Map.ActualWidth + 20) / 2, (Map.ActualHeight + 20) / 2);
    var oldLocation = CanvasScale.Transform(TemplateCanvas.PointFromScreen(relativeMiddle));

    ScaleChanged(scale, CanvasScale);

    var newLocation = CanvasScale.Transform(TemplateCanvas.PointFromScreen(relativeMiddle));

    var shift = newLocation - oldLocation;

    Map.ScrollToVerticalOffset(Map.VerticalOffset + shift.Y);
    Map.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(Map.HorizontalOffset + shift.X);

    lblScale.Content = scale.ToString("P1").Replace(".0", string.Empty);
}
```

Should be quite self-explanatory; the location of the center is measured before and after the scaling to calculate the shift of that point, which then is added to the current scroll-position.

Comment: (H.B.) Just tried to get your code to work, but ... This part of the code is failing -> TemplateCanvas.PointFromScreen(relativeMiddle) with "This Visual is not connected to a PresentationSource."  What do I need to do to get past this?

Comment: @saunderl: You need to check whether the control is loaded, if not defer the handler's execution. I added some code which does that.

Comment: (H.B.) Thank you sir! I also just got it to work by exiting the function if TemplateCanvas was not part of the Visual with:      if (PresentationSource.FromVisual(TemplateCanvas) == null) return;

Comment: @saunderl: The problem with just exiting is that the initial display can be off if the default value does not fit the default scale.

Comment: (H.B.) Very true, but as the sole developer, I can guarantee that.  Thanks again for solving this problem for me.